# drawer menu becomes separate with the toolbar when add login activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

i've made simple application that implement login actvity with firebase authentication. first i made drawer menu in android studio and it still normal, but when i added some classes that name Login the drawer menu becomes like this and i dont know where the cause that make my drawer becomes like this :

[image]
[image]

and this's my MainActicity code :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_cari);

    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void displaySelectedScreen (int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null; // membuat objek dari kelas fragment

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_cari:
            fragment = new MenuPencarian();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_penyewaanku:
            fragment = new MenuPenyewaanku();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_pemberitahuan:
            fragment = new MenuPemberitahuan();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profilku:
            fragment = new MenuProfil();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_tentang:
            fragment = new MenuTentangAplikasi();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_bantuan:
            fragment = new MenuBantuan();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_keluar:
            signOut();
            break;
    }
    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}

//sign out method
public void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }

}`
```

my login.java :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    input_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    input_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    buttonRegistrasi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_registrasi);
    buttonForgetPassword = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    buttonRegistrasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Registrasi.class));
        }
    });

    buttonForgetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = input_email.getText().toString();
            final String password = input_password.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    input_password.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

my login_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mlg4"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.meita.belajar_fragment2.Login">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/orange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        <EditText android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@drawable/round_top_transparant"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColor="@color/putih"
            android:textColorHint="@color/putih"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bottom_transparant"
            android:textColorHint="@color/putih"
            android:textColor="@color/putih"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/hitam"
        android:text="Login"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/putih"
        android:text="Lupa password?"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_registrasi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/putih"
        android:text="Belum punya akun? Daftar Disini"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dip"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:itemIconTint="@color/orange"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

my styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="color">@color/orange</item>
```

Thankyou so much for your help:)

Comment: your theme shouldbe NoActionBar. set it in manifest file

Comment: Replace your AppTheme parent with Light.NoActionBar

Comment: yes, its work thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Try->

Instead of this

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

use:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

and in manifest add this theme to your MainActivity

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ......
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

</activity>
```